# Code Coverage generation for source code and test code in different repository

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, code-coverage

I have one separate project for  main source code and one for test cases. Now while running test project in jenkins job , i want to capture code coverage report for main source code.

I found similar question asked here is:- [Java code coverage for other source code repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223194/java-code-coverage-for-other-source-code-repository)

Please suggest some answer or else what should be the project structure to generate code coverage report for unit test cases.

Answer (score 0):

The [JaCoCo plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) adds a  [JacocoReport](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.html) task to your project. You can configure the additionalClassDirs and additionalSourceDirs properties on that task.

Eg:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco' 
tasks.withType(JacocoReport) {
   additionalClassDirs = ... 
   additionalSourceDirs = ... 
}
```

Comment: How i can do it in jenkins??

Comment: Same as when building locally, you'll need to make the above changes to your `build.gradle`

Comment: tasks.withType(JacocoReport) {
    print("Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii")
    
    def mainSrc = "C:/re-engg/demo-testng/demo-settings-test/src/test/java"
    def mainMainSrc = "C:/re-engg/demo/demo-settings/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    additionalSourceDirs = files([mainMainSrc])
    executionData = files "${projectDir}/demo-settings-test/build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
       html.destination = file("${projectDir}/demo-settings-test/build/jacoco/html")
    }
    
}

Comment: I tried to implement it the way u suggested bu still m not ale to get it.Please help me.