# Jacoco does not compute coverage for child module

Tags: maven, code-coverage, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

Consider a multi-module maven project

```
Parent
    pom.xml
    common
        src->main->java->a -> b 
            SomeUtil.java
    pom.xml
    service
        src->main->test->p->q
            SomeServiceIT.java
    pom.xml
```

Say **service** has a dependency on **common**, and service has **SomeServiceIT** which indirectly tests **SomeUtil** in **common**.

The coverage report produced shows 0% coverage for SomeUtil where it should have shown atleast some coverage.

How do I fix this ?

I am using following plugins

```
jacoco-maven-plugin -> 0.8.1
maven-surefire-plugin -> 2.22.0
maven-failsafe-plugin -> 2.22.0
sonar-maven-plugin -> 3.2
```

Following is my configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <destFile>${project.basedir}/../target/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</destFile>
        <append>true</append>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-merge</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>merge</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <fileSets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/../target/coverage-reports/</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.exec</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </fileSets>
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/../target/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <!-- Separates the unit tests from the integration tests. -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>3C</forkCount>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: First always align surefire/failsafe plugin which means use the same version of them...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jacoco simple integration test solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885772/jacoco-simple-integration-test-solution)