# How do I calculate only Jacoco code coverage of multi-module maven project?

Tags: maven, code-coverage, jacoco, multi-module, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have multi-module maven project structure as shown in image:

[image]

I am simply trying to calculate combined code coverage of webapp1 & webapp2.
I have tried to implement solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031219/how-to-configure-multi-module-maven-sonar-jacoco-to-give-merged-coverage-rep),but as a beginner very less information is given. 
Note: Solutions without use of SonarQube will be good.
Please help me with detailed step to start with.

Comment: Hey @Onkar, welcome on Stack Overflow. As you already found out, the question was answered, so you'll have to give it a try. If you don't have much knowledge about Maven or multi-modules, try to google it. Also, I found [this link](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/MavenMultiModule) which might help you with Jacoco set up. If you'll have a concrete question, which was not answered yet, post it here and we'll try to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jacoco simple integration test solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885772/jacoco-simple-integration-test-solution)