# Jacoco plugin for component tests

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have project structure goes like this

```
myProject
    app
        module1
            submodule
            pom.xml
        pom.xml
    automation
        component-tests
        pom.xml
    pom.xml
pom.xml
```

Using Jacoco maven plugin to score the coverage.

component-tests module includes only test folder **without any sources**. Test is simple unit test that runs application and runs under the hood karate framework which runs full component test of the micro service.

Now after running tests - I see that each module includes jacoco.exec file, regular modules has coverage, however component-tests has jacoco.exec but no data about coverage, somehow it does not perform instrumentation of the all modules code.

I suspect that it is because this module has no sources. I tried to use includes - didn't really helped, since I think it is working in scope of the module.

Below is maven surefire argument
`javaagent:/Users/me/.m2/repo/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.10/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.10-runtime`

Any option to turn calculation of coverage of whole project when I run component test module?

```
<profiles>
<profile>
  <id>coverage</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.11</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-jacoco-coverage</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <argLine>
          ${surefireArgLine}
        </argLine>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jacoco simple integration test solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885772/jacoco-simple-integration-test-solution)

Comment: Tried to bring all classes - didn't really helped.

Comment: Did you try to exclude/skip the plugin execution for the jacoco plugin and jacoco reporting plugin in the respective projects that have no cod to determine coverage for?

Comment: Not sure how it should help me. I want to run jacoco for the module which has no source and has only test. Let's call it integration test. But I want to see coverage of all modules it triggers

Comment: Please show the pom file... also which Maven version, JDK version etc. you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here all the answers that I needed

https://medium.com/javarevisited/merging-integration-unit-and-functional-test-reports-with-jacoco-de5cde9b56e1