# Jcoco exce check goal error - Analyzed bundle 'jacoco-merge' with 0 classes

Tags: maven-3, jacoco-maven-plugin

I wanted to run jacoco-check goal in multi module project. The issue I am having is, even after setting the dataFile location it couldn't find the file.

After implementing the jacoco-merge with multi module project I am able to generate the merge `jacoco.exec` file in

```
main-project\target\jacoco.exec
```

I have below code for the jacoco-check

```
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>merge-results</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>merge</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <destFile>${user.dir}/target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                                <fileSets>
                                    <fileSet>
                                        <!-- This is where the individual builds put results -->
                                        <directory>${user.dir}/target/jacoco</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>*.exec</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileSet>
                                </fileSets>
                            </configuration>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-merge-report</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <dataFile>${user.dir}/target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                                <outputDirectory>${user.dir}/target/coverage-reports</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-check</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                              <dataFile>${user.dir}/target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                                <rules>
                                    <rule>
                                        <limits>
                                            <limit>
                                                <counter>LINE</counter>
                                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                                <minimum>80%</minimum>
                                            </limit>
                                        </limits>
                                    </rule>
                                </rules>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

But after running mvn verify I see below error in the logs relating to check goals

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.3:merge (merge-results) @ jacoco-merge ---
    [INFO] Loading execution data file c:main-project\target\jacoco\module1.exec
    [INFO] Loading execution data file c:main-project\target\jacoco\module2.exec
    [INFO] Writing merged execution data to c:main-project\target\jacoco.exec
.....
    [INFO] Loading execution data file c:main-project\jacoco-merge\target\jacoco.exec
    [INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.3:check (jacoco-check) @ jacoco-merge ---
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'jacoco-merge' with 0 classes
```

Comment: After I removed `<dataFile>${user.dir}/target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>` section it gives an error `[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file:c:main-project\jacoco-merge\target\jacoco.exec`

Comment: I tried this solutions as well, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37416679, I added `maven-resources-plugin` plugin. But the problem there is copying happening after `jacoco-check`

Comment: I then tried to copy merge `jacoco.exec` file into both directories i.e. `${basedir}/target` and `${basedir}/target/classes` . Then new error says `Analyzed bundle 'jacoco-merge' with 0 classes`